# Removing blocked users from the pipeline with lookup in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, nosql, aggregation-framework, nosql-aggregation

On Mongodb, I have a "conversations2" collection where I keep chat data and a "user_blocked" collection that I keep blocked by the system. While pulling the chats according to userId, I need to pull the IDs in user_blocked that do not match otherUserId. My query below works, but it is too slow for users with a high number of messages (for example, there are 450 thousand records for a user with 32 IDs). Is there a chance I can speed this up or receive this query via a different route? (My goal is to get the user's unread message count, excluding any blocking) Thanks in advance for your help. By the way, userId_1 and otherUserId_1 indexes in conversations2 are added. The id_1 index is added in user_blocked.

```
db.conversations2.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      userId: 32
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "user_blocked",
      localField: "otherUserId",
      foreignField: "id",
      as: "blockedUsers"
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      blockedUsers: {
        $eq: []
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$userId",
      unreadMessageCount: {
        $sum: "$unreadMessageCount"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

conversations2 collection example data ;

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "65c0f64030054c4b8f0481a0"
  },
  "otherUserId": {
    "$numberLong": "45"
  },
  "userId": {
    "$numberLong": "32"
  },
  "lastMessage": "test",
  "lastMessageTime": {
    "$date": "2024-02-21T10:36:44.592Z"
  },
  "lastMessageType": 1,
  "lastMessageWay": "in",
  "unreadMessageCount": 29
}
```

user_blocked example data;

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "66033f989bba279fe7d0862a"
  },
  "id": {
    "$numberLong": "45"
  }
}
```

Comment: **1.** Could you edit your question to post some samples of the `conversations2` documents for userID 32? Exclude fields that are not relevant to the question, like datetime, etc. **2.** And also include `user_blocked`. Better than us assuming each document is just `{id: 1234}`. **3.** Is `otherUserID` an array? Or is it always 1-to-1 conversations? **4.** How _big_ is the `user_blocked` collection? **5.** Some optimisations may involve changing the data structure of the `conversations2` documents. Is that a  possibility?

Comment: Hello, I added sample data in both collections.

Comment: So is `user_blocked.id` just an integer but `conversations2.otherUserId` is NumberLong? If so, then Mongo needs to convert the types before matching, even if it can use the index after the conversion. Also, you said _"My query below works"_ but [it clearly doesn't](https://mongoplayground.net/p/E46UhxX141Q). **User 45 is blocked** so with just that one record of sample data, total `unreadMessageCount` should be 0, not 29.

Comment: First of all, thank you for your help. I realized my mistake and corrected it https://mongoplayground.net/p/qlNfMOte0kp. But unfortunately my performance problem continues. I will update the user_blocked collection to numberLong and try again, I hope this works. If there is anything you can suggest differently, I can ask for it.

Comment: I updated user_blocked.id to numberlong, but unfortunately it still returns very slowly. Also when I watch from performance it's 5819348.08%
  I see a usage in user_blocked collection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### 1. Only check for `unread > 0`

Since you're getting only `unreadMessageCount` in this query, the first minor optimisation is to add that to your first `$match` stage. Since the total is unchanged when it's `0`, whether the user is blocked or not.

```js
{
  $match: {
    userId: 32,
    unreadMessageCount: { $gt: 0 }
  }
}
```

#### 2. Uncorrelated Subquery with `$lookup`

##### 2A.

We can also try to optimise the number of `$lookup`s which actually occur. By using an [**Uncorrelated Subquery with `$lookup`**](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#perform-an-uncorrelated-subquery-with--lookup) - ie it only runs once and not for every document.

```js
db.conversations2.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      userId: 32,
      unreadMessageCount: { $gt: 0 }
    }
  },
  {
    // this will only run once
    $lookup: {
      from: "user_blocked",
      pipeline: [
        {
          $group: {
            _id: null,
            ids: { $addToSet: "$id" }
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "blockedUsers"
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      blockedUsers: { $first: "$blockedUsers.ids" }
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      $expr: {
        $eq: [
          { $indexOfArray: ["$blockedUsers", "$otherUserId"] },
          -1
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$userId",
      unreadMessageCount: {
        $sum: "$unreadMessageCount"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/7bw9WDeLaOv) with the correct result of unread `10`

However, if your `user_blocked` collection is too big, you may hit the 16MB per-stage limit (1.3 mil ids for Ints, ~600k for Longs), followed by the 100MB limit with `allowDiskUse: true`. In that case use variation B below:

##### 2B.

This aggregation pipeline will reduce the total number of lookups needed and has less chance of running into stage-size limits but it still might. Steps:

- Get all the `otherIDs` into a single array
- Do a one-time lookup on `user_blocked`
- Retain only the remaining `validOtherIDs`
- Do a self-lookup of `conversations2` but only with the `validOtherIDs`

```js
db.conversations2.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      userId: 32,
      unreadMessageCount: { $gt: 0 }
    }
  },
  {
    // collect all the unique `otherUserId` for this userId
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      otherUserIds: { $addToSet: "$otherUserId" }
    }
  },
  {
    // correlated but will only run once since
    // the previous stage has only one document
    $lookup: {
      from: "user_blocked",
      let: {
        lookupOtherUserIds: "$otherUserIds"
      },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $ne: [
                { $indexOfArray: ["$$lookupOtherUserIds", "$id"] },
                -1
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          $group: {
            _id: null,
            ids: { $addToSet: "$id" }
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "blockedUsers"
    }
  },
  {
    // otherIDs which remain after removing blockedIDs
    $project: {
      validOtherIds: {
        $setDifference: ["$otherUserIds", { $first: "$blockedUsers.ids" }]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    // do a self-lookup on `conversations2`
    $lookup: {
      from: "conversations2",
      let: {
        lookupValidOtherIds: "$validOtherIds"
      },
      // repeat part of the first stage of this pipeline, yuck!
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            userId: 32,
            // unread > 0 check is not needed since
            // lookupValidOtherIds already has only > 0's
            $expr: {
              $ne: [
                { $indexOfArray: ["$$lookupValidOtherIds", "$otherUserId"] },
                -1
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "validConvos"
    }
  },
  // the `group` below can be directly done in the self-lookup stage
  // but I find this cleaner
  { $unwind: "$validConvos" },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      unreadMessageCount: {
        $sum: "$validConvos.unreadMessageCount"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/cz_bOiijLqo)

#### 3. ‼ No lookups, Add a field `otherUserBlocked`

This optimisation will require a data/structure change but is the **most scalable and most performant**:

Add a field like `otherUserBlocked: true/false` and index it. Initially default it to `false` (no users blocked) and then set it to `true` using a similar pipeline to the one you already have.

<sup>If you skip initial defaults, you'll need to have clauses `{ otherUserBlocked: { $exists: true } }` added to the queries below.</sup>

Each time a user gets blocked, you're already adding them to `user_blocked` collection. Add another step to also update `conversations2` with `{ $match: { otherUserId: blocked_user_id } }` and set `otherUserBlocked: true`. Something like:

```js
db.conversations2.updateMany({
  otherUserId: 46
},
{
  $set: {
    otherUserBlocked: true
  }
})
```

And if they get unblocked, set it `false`.

Your aggregation pipeline can then use this in the first `$match` stage and eliminates the need for the `$lookup` completely, as well as the second `$match` stage. The pipeline becomes:

```js
db.conversations2.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      userId: 32,
      otherUserBlocked: false,
      unreadMessageCount: { $gt: 0 }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$userId",
      unreadMessageCount: { $sum: "$unreadMessageCount" }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground with the new field](https://mongoplayground.net/p/DE3tX_f2RVb)

Both of these changes will also be useful when you want to actually show the unread messages, and not just the count.

More about [MongoDB Schema Design best practices](https://www.mongodb.com/developer/products/mongodb/mongodb-schema-design-best-practices/#embedding-vs--referencing).

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. The first suggestion, unread > 0, seriously solves my problem. But it is false-true for the long term, so the second solution you suggested will also solve it. I have a case left. Except for the situation where the room user is blocked in the system, the situation where users block each other. {
   "_id": { "$oid": "660129b9971c08e082e08a76" },
   "user_id_owner": 32, "user_id_target": 45 } there is data like this. The user may block someone or the other party may block the user, in which case I should not count unread. What would you recommend for this?

Comment: I've added two more aggregation options 2A & 2B which don't require a structure change. But those pipelines still have limitations. Wrt users blocking each other or users being blocked by the party; use a similar approach. And if you are unable to solve it, ask another question and provide valid example data, attempted code and expected result.

Comment: I've already started implementing the 3rd solution, I'm grateful. But the question I just asked is actually a little different. I have two different collections. One of them is user_blocked, which we mentioned before, and here we have system blocks. The other one is user_blocks (where { "_id": { "$oid": "660129b9971c08e082e08a76" }, "user_id_owner": 32, "user_id_target": 45 }) I keep the status of two users blocking each other. I shouldn't count unread for users who block each other. What kind of a similar solution would you suggest here without using lookup?

Comment: For an example, you can check it out here: https://mongoplayground.net/p/5UOXnkNFA6i

Comment: `user_blocks` & `user_blocked` are _terrible_ collection name combinations. Try `system_blocks` and `user_blocks` instead. You can add a similar field in `conversations2` like `otherUserSystemBlocked` and `otherUserUserBlocked` or just `systemBlocked` and `userBlocked`. Otherwise, you will need to modify your pipelines to lookup these new collections and add them to `validOtherIds` like in example 2B. Try some solutions yourself and ask another question if you get stuck. Remember to include **example data** which you [forgot in your previous comment](https://mongoplayground.net/p/5UOXnkNFA6i).

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answers, I will contact you if I need anything else.

Comment: No lol, don't contact me. StackOverflow is not that kind of site. [Ask a separate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).